# Cannot write to BLE characteristics

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I use iPhone 4S.

I successfully send data from nordic nrf81522 to my iOS APP, but when I try to send data back to nordic on another characteristic I receive an error:

```
didWriteValueForCharacteristic 2A38 error = Error Domain=CBErrorDomain
Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo=0x165ee7e0
{NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.}
```

What does this error means?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the characteristic flagged as writeable on your Nordic?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to write characteristic 2A38, which is the [sensor location attribute](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.body_sensor_location.xml) for a heart-rate monitor

This is a read-only attribute as you can't change the location of a sensor simply by writing a new value to a characteristic.

Comment: Just for my test i want to send location from my ios APP to nordic.
it is possible?

Comment: Yes, but you need to work out what profiles are loaded into your device and find a writable attribute.

Comment: I tried to do it. The project has HRS service with , battery service and Device info.

i modified the hrs location characteristic to be a write open, but it is still has the same error